# Hibernation in windows

Tags: windows, hibernate

Does hibernation in Windows write the entire contents of RAM to disk?  Or just the addresses/contents of what has been allocated?  Just curious, as it would seem wasteful to write a bunch of random data that will not be called.

Comment: Basically answered by https://superuser.com/questions/887455/how-can-windows-dump-the-complete-ram-in-the-hibernation-file-so-fast?rq=1

Comment: Yes; Hibernation does indeed dump the system state to a file.