# Hiberfil.sys is taking gbs of HDD space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. Today I saw that Disk:C is totally full. I don't take it seriously but after some time many errors started to occur.

Some of the errors say that the disk hasn't enough space to proceed. Then I go to Disk:C, select all folders and click on properties but the properties panel said that all the files took only 45.6gb of space.

Then I clicked at show hidden files and operating system protected files. Then the problem is front of me. The file name *hiberfil.sys* is of 126.9gb. I cannot understand what caused this file to take so much memory. Its name is something related to hibernation mode.

I decided to delete this file but no sucess even booting in safe mode.

I am sure that is not not a Windows bug because I have all the updates installed.

Because it has taken almost all space I can't do anything instead of rebooting windows.
Do you have any recommendations for solutions I can try?

Comment: Its what the Computer uses to Store the Hibernation Settings to remove it follow [This Guide Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15140/what-is-hiberfil.sys-and-how-do-i-delete-it/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `hiberfil.sys` is required to store your RAM to disk in case of hibernation. It does not need to be bigger than you RAM, and is typically 75% of it. So unless you have ~170GB main memory, yours is way to big.

You can delete the file by disabling hibernation: open a command prompt in admin mode and type `powercfg -H off`.

You can re-enable hibernation, which creates a new `hiberfil.sys`, with `powercfg -H on`.

With `powercfg -H -Size <PercentSize>`, you can set the desired size of the file in percent of your main memory (can't be less than 50).

Answer (score 1):

Hiberfil.sys should be the same size as your RAM, so do you have 128 GB or RAM ?

To get rid of it do these steps, taken from
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730

This should erase hiberfil.sys, you might want to do a disk corruption check before to make sure your drive is not failing and giving the wrong size because of that. Also I would backup my files if I suspected my disk might be failing.

To make hibernation unavailable, follow these steps:
Click Start, and then type cmd in the Start Search box.
In the search results list, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.
When you are prompted by User Account Control, click Continue.
At the command prompt, type powercfg.exe /hibernate off, and then press Enter.
Type exit, and then press Enter to close the Command Prompt window.

Comment: Since Windows 7 the data in the hibernation file is compressed and the size is adjustable so it should actually be *less* than the available RAM. http://superuser.com/a/746304/19943