# How to identify and remove unnecessary files from Windows Driverstore?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

My `Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` is **48 Gigabytes** in size.

That is way bigger than I have ever seen anywhere else, and is way out of proportion for a 128GB SSD.

I know how to list the files in it, and I know how to delete them individually.

What I do not know is **Which drivers are unnecessary, and which can I delete?**

I use Windows 7, Home Premium, with Service pack 1, and fully up to date.

Windows Disk Cleanup and PrivaZer have not reduced the file size.

The question [How do I delete folders from the Windows 7 DriverStore?](https://superuser.com/questions/597370/how-do-i-delete-folders-from-the-windows-7-driverstore) is not a duplicate of this one because it does not ask **How do I know a driver in the driver store CAN be safely deleted?**

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/499397/23133) to [How to reduce the size (disk space) of Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/499366/how-to-reduce-the-size-disk-space-of-windows-8)

Comment: dism /Online /Remove-Driver /Driver:oem1.inf
    Replace the **oem1.inf** with the **INF** name of the driver.  Be care full not to remove something important.

Comment: From Admin Command Prompt:  **dism /Online /Get-Drivers /Format:Table /all**  Copy and Paste the results into Excel or etc sort by name and see how many version of the same thing you have.